# Key issue with installing RVM (Ruby Version Manager)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, centos6, pgp

I am trying to install the Ruby Version Manager( RVM) on my CentOS 6.6 machine.

I followed the instructions on the home page at https://rvm.io/rvm/install

When I run this command :

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

I keep getting the error :

```
gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'keys.gnupg.net'
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks
IS

Comment: Do any hostname lookups work for you?

Comment: Can you resolve hostnames? Try to ping google.

Comment: Yes, there are no problems resolving to most major web sites like Google from that machine.  So I tried the replace the keyserver keys.gnupg.net with an alternative keyserver pgp.mit.edu  , and now it works fine

Answer (score 38):

You can download the signature and import it manually.

```
curl -#LO https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
gpg --import mpapis.asc
```

And now install RVM. That should work

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

**Note:**

If you have a `.gnupg` directory, remove it first.

```
rm -rf ~/.gnupg/
```

Comment: This also worked for me on a Macintosh running El Capitan.

Comment: Worked for me on Mac running Mojave

Comment: this just worked for me on a Redhat 7 serer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The one at fault here is [`virtualbox`'s dns proxy](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14736). The issue manifests itself only under `vagrant`, because the latter enables it (dns proxy). By default it's disabled. So, one way to remedy it is to disable dns proxy (`VBoxManage modifyvm ... --natdnsproxy off`). Or change `10.0.2.3` in `/etc/resolv.conf` to your host's resolver IP address. And do `gpg` again, while it didn't change. Or, do `gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys D39DC0E3`. Which succeeds for a reason I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gpg --keyserver 213.133.103.71 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

an IP instead of hkp://keys.gnupg.net

Comment: I would upvote you, but then I realise the IP is wrong. If I was the suspicious type, I'd think you control this IP :-)

Comment: No, I has same problem. I can ping "keys.gnupg.net", also I replaced domain name with it's IP address.But faced same error. @Jay answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue while trying to upgrade from docker to docker for Mac on one of our Ubuntu images for ruby.

Here is my workaround:

```
gpg --keyserver $(getent hosts keys.gnupg.net | awk '{ print $1 }' | head -1) --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

This resolved the issue and seemed to be the least hacky solution.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after I added google's DNS `8.8.8.8` in network settings.

Answer (score -1):

The right workaround to this issue is:

```
gpg --keyserver $(ping keys.gnupg.net) --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```