# gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host stack overflow

Tags: rvm, host, gnupg, keyserver

While attempting to set up fastlane for my iOS application, I encountered challenges while installing RVM.

My command is

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113************* 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D69561*************
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31000710 This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 39):

Please use

```
hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net
```

instead of

```
hkp://keys.gnupg.net
```

type this command

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113************* 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D69561*************
```

Comment: Just to note, the official RVM documentation says to use `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` without the `ipv4` prepended to the URL in the first step of installing GPG keys. Adding the ipv4 here fixes the issue.

Comment: In case above server is not responding or facing any issue you can try any of the below one 

hkp://pgp.mit.edu
hkp://keyserver.pgp.com

https://rvm.io/rvm/security

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR;** The list of key servers is unstable and some of them are not pingeable at all. Here's a way of finding an available server

I've tried different key servers and got a

`gpg: keyserver receive failed: No route to host` or a `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Operation timed out`

You have to find a server that's up and running correctly

1. Run `gpg-connect-agent --dirmngr 'keyserver --hosttable'` to get the list of available servers
2. Run the `gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C2………………6956105BD0E739499BDB` and instead of `hkp://pool.sks...` try few of the servers URL

src: https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b

Answer (score 0):

Ik it's late but for future references

rvm mentioned alternative servers on there website you can use any of them. Mentioned servers as of now are below ones

```
hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net
hkp://pgp.mit.edu
hkp://keyserver.pgp.com
```

Check list here: https://rvm.io/rvm/security